# Corona SDK, Removing object from previous scene

Tags: coronasdk

When the scene ends, the "sendObject" function ends, however the remaining display objects on screen, continue to next scene, until their transition process has finished. I've tried including "object:removeSelf()" to both the scene:hide, and finishGame functions, both resulting in a nil value error. Any suggestions?

```html
local composer = require("composer")
local scene = composer.newScene()
local physics = require("physics")
local gameData = require("gamedata")
physics.start()
local player
local object = {}
local gameIsOver = false;
local objectCounter = 1
local objectFrequency = 2500
local objectTmr
local numberOfLives = 1


function scene:create(event)
    local group = self.view

    sendObject()
end

function scene:show(event)
    local phase = event.phase
    local previousScene = composer.getSceneName("previous")
    composer.removeScene(previousScene)
    local group = self.view
    if ( phase == "did" ) then
        Runtime:addEventListener("collision", onCollision)
    end
end

function scene:hide(event)
    local phase = event.phase
    local group = self.view
    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        Runtime:removeEventListener("collision", onCollision)
        timer.cancel(objectTmr)
    end
end

function sendObject()
    object[objectCounter] = display.newImageRect("object.png", 40, 40)
    object[objectCounter].name = "object"
    object[objectCounter].x = math.random(5, 475)
    object[objectCounter].y = -125
    physics.addBody(object[objectCounter])
    object[objectCounter].bodyType = "kinematic"

    transition.to(object[objectCounter], {y=display.contentHeight+object[objectCounter].height+20, time=8500, onComplete=function(self) display.remove(self); end})

    objectCounter = objectCounter + 1
    if(objectCounter%2 == 0) then
        objectFrequency = objectFrequency - 200
        if(objectFrequency < 800) 
            then objectFrequency = 800
        end
        timer.cancel(objectTmr)
        objectTmr = timer.performWithDelay(objectFrequency, sendObject, 0)
    end
end
objectTmr = timer.performWithDelay(objectFrequency, sendObject, 0)

function onCollision(event)
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        if(event.object1.name == "player" and event.object2.name == "object") then
            canMove = false
            numberOfLives = 0
            finishGame()
        end
        if(event.object1.name == "object" and event.object2.name == "player") then
            canMove = false
            numberOfLives = 0
            finishGame()
        end
    end
end

function finishGame()
    gameIsOver = true
    numberOfLives = numberOfLives - 1
    if(numberOfLives <= 0) then
        composer.gotoScene("gameover")
    end
end

function scene:destroy(event)

end

scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene)
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene)


return scene
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function sendObject()
    object[objectCounter] = display.newImageRect(scene.view, "object.png", 40, 40)
...
```

From Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/system/composer/index.html)

> Remember that you must insert scene display objects into the scene's
>   self.view group. If you create display objects but do not insert them
>   into this group, they will reside in front of the Composer stage and
>   they will not be regarded as part of the scene. For display objects
>   which should be part of the scene and "managed" by Composer — for
>   example, cleaned up when the scene is removed — you must insert them
>   into the scene's self.view group